# How to send request on click React Hooks way?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to send http request on button click with react hooks? Or, for that matter, how to do any side effect on button click?

What i see so far is to have something "indirect" like:

```
export default = () => {
  const [sendRequest, setSendRequest] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(sendRequest){
       //send the request
       setSendRequest(false);
    }
  },
  [sendRequest]);

  return (
    <input type="button" disabled={sendRequest} onClick={() => setSendRequest(true)}
  );
}
```

Is that the proper way or is there some other pattern?

Comment: I think that there is no point in using react hooks to do that, you can just have a normal function withing your component and have it as your input event handler.

Comment: how about the point that `render` (thus sfc) shouldn't have side effects?

Comment: Using a hook would make the code far more flexible, but its a temporary measure as soon React will handle this using Suspense, see https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/ for more information.

Comment: @dorriz yes yes, over time, suspense will be added to this story. but until then, lets pretend suspend doesn't/won't exist.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
export default () => {
  const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false)
  const sendRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    // don't send again while we are sending
    if (isSending) return
    // update state
    setIsSending(true)
    // send the actual request
    await API.sendRequest()
    // once the request is sent, update state again
    setIsSending(false)
  }, [isSending]) // update the callback if the state changes

  return (
    <input type="button" disabled={isSending} onClick={sendRequest} />
  )
}
```

this is what it would boil down to when you want to send a request on click and disabling the button while it is sending

## update:

@tkd_aj pointed out that this might give a warning: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

Effectively, what happens is that the request is still processing, while in the meantime your component unmounts. It then tries to `setIsSending` (a setState) on an unmounted component.

```
export default () => {
  const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false)
  const isMounted = useRef(true)

  // set isMounted to false when we unmount the component
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    // don't send again while we are sending
    if (isSending) return
    // update state
    setIsSending(true)
    // send the actual request
    await API.sendRequest()
    // once the request is sent, update state again
    if (isMounted.current) // only update if we are still mounted
      setIsSending(false)
  }, [isSending]) // update the callback if the state changes

  return (
    <input type="button" disabled={isSending} onClick={sendRequest} />
  )
}
```

Comment: so, 1. setting the flag in state which then gets picked up by some other hook (be it `useEffect` or `useCallback`) is the proper way? 2. could you please include a sentence of explanation why would you prefer using `useCallback` instead of `useCallback`? tnx!

Comment: useCallback instead of useEffect you mean? Well, because it's a callback and not a side-effect

Comment: well, depends on how you treat it. if you use reactive/declarative way, it can be `sideEffect`. if you use imperative way, it can be a callback. both work. but i see your point, of course.

Comment: `await API.sendRequest()` is an effect, so I guess this code would behave in unpredictable ways. I'd consider using `useEffect`.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using useEffect. To do that, it would become an effect triggered by a state-change, which would also cause an unnecessary re-render. Callbacks are inherently side-effects when they are triggered by a user-action.

Comment: Whenever I use this method I get "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."  Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: @tkd_aj this means that the actual request is resolved after the component is dismounted. I'll update my code to give an example on how to solve that :-)

Comment: Thank you for your update!  That worked like a charm.  What I'm confused about, though, is my button is disabled like it should be, and re-renabled after the API call like it should be, but it wouldn't be calling the second "setIsSending" call since isMounted.current is false (otherwise it wouldn't have been throwing an error before, right?) . So how does my button get reenabled?  Also, why does the component unmount in the first place if I haven't navigated away, and I don't have any conditional rendering on the component?

Comment: It is woking when second click. If i click the button very first time, it is throwing an error.Next Click its working Perfect.

Comment: Totally wrong! react do patch update after the function completely finish this means the loading will show up after the function finish

Answer (score 28):

You don't need an effect to send a request on button click, instead what you need is just a handler method which you can optimise using `useCallback` method

```
const App = (props) => {
   //define you app state here
   const fetchRequest = useCallback(() => {
       // Api request here
   }, [add dependent variables here]);

  return (
    <input type="button" disabled={sendRequest} onClick={fetchRequest}
  );
}
```

Tracking request using variable with `useEffect` is not a correct pattern because you may set state to call api using useEffect, but an additional render due to some other change will cause the request to go in a loop

Comment: @deezg glad to have helped :-)

Comment: Why are you using useCallback here? What's the purpose of memoizing the onClick handler?

Comment: @Hardwork : so that function is not recreated on each component renders. Function is object in javascript and will be recreated on each render.. usecallback will avoid this

Answer (score 11):

In functional programming, any async function should be considered as a side effect.

When dealing with side effects you need to separate the logic of starting the side effect and the logic of the result of that side effect (similar to redux saga).

Basically, the button responsibility is only triggering the side effect, and the side effect responsibility is to update the dom.

Also since react is dealing with components you need to make sure your component still mounted before any `setState` or after every `await` this depends on your own preferences.

to solve this issue we can create a custom hook `useIsMounted` this hook will make it easy for us to check if the component is still mounted

```
/**
 * check if the component still mounted
 */
export const useIsMounted = () => {
  const mountedRef = useRef(false);
  const isMounted = useCallback(() => mountedRef.current, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    mountedRef.current = true;
    return () => {
      mountedRef.current = false;
    };
  });

  return isMounted;
};
```

Then your code should look like this

```
export const MyComponent = ()=> {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();
  const [isDoMyAsyncThing, setIsDoMyAsyncThing] = useState(false);

  // do my async thing
  const doMyAsyncThing = useCallback(async () => {
     // do my stuff
  },[])

  /**
   * do my async thing effect
  */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDoMyAsyncThing) {
      const effect = async () => {
        await doMyAsyncThing();
        if (!isMounted()) return;
        setIsDoMyAsyncThing(false);
      };
      effect();
    }
  }, [isDoMyAsyncThing, isMounted, doMyAsyncThing]);

  return (
     <div> 
        <button disabled={isDoMyAsyncThing} onClick={()=> setIsDoMyAsyncThing(true)}>
          Do My Thing {isDoMyAsyncThing && "Loading..."}
        </button>;
     </div>
  )
}
```

**Note:** It's always better to separate the logic of your side effect from the logic that triggers the effect (the `useEffect`)

**UPDATE:**

Instead of all the above complexity just use [`useAsync`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsync.md) and [`useAsyncFn`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsyncFn.md) from the [`react-use`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) library, It's much cleaner and straightforward.

**Example:**

```js
import {useAsyncFn} from 'react-use';

const Demo = ({url}) => {

  const [state, doFetch] = useAsyncFn(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.text();
    return result
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.loading
        ? <div>Loading...</div>
        : state.error
          ? <div>Error: {state.error.message}</div>
          : <div>Value: {state.value}</div>
      }
      <button onClick={() => doFetch()}>Start loading</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The best answer, especially the recommendation on `react-use`.

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch data as an effect of some state changing like you have done in your question, but you can also get the data directly in the click handler like you are used to in a class component.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 1000))
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0)

  function onClick() {
    getData().then(setData)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Get data</button>
      <div>{data}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Apparently the OP is trying to disable the button which triggers the request, so probably you'll have to add `setData(0)` in your `onClick`

Comment: what is the preferred way and why? also, what would you say about `render`/sfc shouldn't cause side-effects? here, our rendered content depends on the state of the request (sent, pending, response)

Comment: @deezg It's very context specific and mostly a matter of opinion. If your effect has a lot of dependencies, it might be better to use an effect, but if there is just one piece of state like in my example it's easy to have the logic directly in the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the boolean in the state as you did and once you trigger the request set it to `true` and when you receive the response set it back to `false`:

```
const [requestSent, setRequestSent] = useState(false);

const sendRequest = () => {
  setRequestSent(true);
  fetch().then(() => setRequestSent(false));
};
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko407q1v93)

Comment: i might very well be wrong, but isn't sfc meant to be side-effects free? i know this works, but it introduces side-effects without actual use of effects-like hooks. is that recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook `useApi` and return a function `execute` which when called will invoke the api (typically through some `onClick`).

`useApi` hook:

```
export type ApiMethod = "GET" | "POST";

export type ApiState = "idle" | "loading" | "done";

const fetcher = async (
    url: string,
    method: ApiMethod,
    payload?: string
  ): Promise<any> => {
    const requestHeaders = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
  
    console.log("fetching data...");
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      body: payload ? JSON.stringify(payload) : undefined,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      method,
    });
  
    const resobj = await res.json();
    return resobj;
  };

export function useApi(
  url: string,
  method: ApiMethod,
  payload?: any
): {
  apiState: ApiState;
  data: unknown;
  execute: () => void;
} {
  const [apiState, setApiState] = useState<ApiState>("idle");

  const [data, setData] = useState<unknown>(null);
  const [toCallApi, setApiExecution] = useState(false);

  const execute = () => {
    console.log("executing now");
    setApiExecution(true);
  };


  const fetchApi = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("fetchApi called");
    fetcher(url, method, payload)
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        setData({ ...data });
        return;
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => {
        setData(null);
        console.log(e.message);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setApiState("done");
      });
  }, [method, payload, url]);

  // call api
  useEffect(() => {
    if (toCallApi &&  apiState === "idle") {
      console.log("calling api");
      setApiState("loading");
      fetchApi();
    }
  }, [apiState, fetchApi, toCallApi]);

  return {
    apiState,
    data,
    execute,
  };
}
```

using `useApi` in some component:

```
const SomeComponent = () =>{

const { apiState, data, execute } = useApi(
      "api/url",
      "POST",
      {
        foo: "bar",
      }
    );

}

if (apiState == "done") {
      console.log("execution complete",data);
}

return (
 <button
   onClick={() => {
            execute();
          }}>
Click me
</button>
);
```

Comment: If it returns a function then why not just export your function regularly?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use callback hook in ReactJS and it is the best option for this purpose as useEffect is not a correct pattern because may be you set state to make an api call using useEffect, but an additional render due to some other change will cause the request to go in a loop.

```
 <const Component= (props) => {
       //define you app state here
       const getRequest = useCallback(() => {
           // Api request here
       }, [dependency]);
    
      return (
        <input type="button" disabled={sendRequest} onClick={getRequest}
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is simple, while using the useState hook the javascript doesn't enable you to pass the value if you set the state as false. It accepts the value when it is set to true. So you have to define a function with if condition if you use false in the usestate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).