# React navigations auth flow issue: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation in my React native app.
Also I'm using Redux as a state management.

I have a navigation component that checks user from the redux store and defines `Navigation`;

```
export const AppNavigator = ({auth}) => {
  const defineNavigator = () => {
    if (isClientUser(auth)) return <ClientNavigator />;
    if (isSellerUser(auth)) return <SellerNavigator />;
    return <AuthNavigator />;
  };

  return <NavigationContainer>{defineNavigator()}</NavigationContainer>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppNavigator);
```

The issue occurs when I dispatch `login` action:

```
  const submit = () => {
    form.sms_code = filterValidationCode(code);
    setLoading(true);

    userService
      .register(form)
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch(login(data));
        userService
          .getAuthUser()
          .then((data) => dispatch(fetchAuthUser(data)))
          .catch((err) => setApiError(responseErrFromAPI(err)))
          .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (
          err.response &&
          err.response.data &&
          err.response.data.error === BAD_USERNAME_ERROR
        ) {
          setApiError(i18n.t('errors.phone_exists'));
        } else {
          setApiError(responseErrFromAPI(err));
        }
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };
```

I tried to solve the problem using `useEffect` hook as mentioned:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647287/how-to-send-request-on-click-react-hooks-way)

But did not help.

I think that the problem in `AppNavigator` as is listens for the `auth` state.
Any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: What is the `userService` doing for you then? Seems if a user authenticates the Navigator is swapped out and any subsequent "actions"/state updates in `submit` are rather irrelevant.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your reply. userService makes http request for server (using axios), sending data to server. And it returns Promise,

Comment: Do you need to wait for it I guess is more my question. Seems all it does is set loading false if a user successfully authenticated (but the UI has already updated so this fails), and (presumably) an error with failed authentication and the `auth` state doesn't change (and swap the Navigator)? If `userService.getAuthUser()` is integral to your app's `auth` state you need to rethink the login flow.

Comment: @DrewReese can you advise some examples or patterns for this?