# How delete/edit Firestore document from collection with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

So I have a simple CRUD App with React using Firebase Firestore, and I have a bunch of collection. Inside each collection I have images object with images.
I can’t find a way to delete or edit these images.
For the moment I’m able to fetch and displays images by there collection.

There is my code. I want to add delete and an edit button inside the .

Please help...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouteMatch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { NewPhoto } from "./NewPhoto";
import { app } from "./base";

const db = app.firestore();

export const Album = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [albumName, setAlbumName] = useState("");

  const match = useRouteMatch("/:album");
  const { album } = match.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    const unmount = db.collection("albums")
      .doc(album)
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        setImages(doc.data().images || []);
        setAlbumName(doc.data().name);
      });
      return unmount
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <header>
          <h1>{albumName}</h1>
          <p>Go to the <Link to="/">Home page</Link></p>
        </header>
        {images.map((image) => (
          <aside key={image.name}>
            <img src={image.url} alt="album" />
          </aside>
        ))}
      </section>
      <footer>
        <NewPhoto currentAlbum={album} />
      </footer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is the code/function that performs the delete?

Comment: That's the case, I've tried many different code, but none of them works.
I initially try to delete by :
 deleteImage(id)
    {
      db.collection("album").doc(image[id]).delete()
    }

Comment: `delete()` returns a `Promise` so you might want to put a `then()` or `catch()` or `await` it.  Also, I can't see any button in your code.

Comment: Yes, because i didn't implement it, cause it doesn't works.

an you explain by given me an exemple of how to write delete function to delete one item of an firestore document ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve or what your document looks like, is your url image as a string in the doc or is it stored in the firebase storage.

Deleting docs is relatively simple as long as you have the doc reference, [see these guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) on how to delete documents or if you want to delete a field within a doc [see these guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data). If you want to remove your image from storage look at [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files).

Alternatively if you just want to update that string your can use [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) to guide you

To add that functionality to your code under a button you could do something like what is detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647287/how-to-send-request-on-click-react-hooks-way)

Maybe something like this would work for you;

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useRouteMatch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { NewPhoto } from "./NewPhoto";
import { app } from "./base";

const db = app.firestore();

export const Album = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [albumName, setAlbumName] = useState("");
  const [isSending, setSending] = useState(false);

  const match = useRouteMatch("/:album");
  const { album } = match.params;

  const deleteDoc =  useCallback((indexToRemove) => {
    setSending(true);
    db.collection("albums")
      .doc(album)
      .update('images', Firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(indexToRemove))
   .then (()=>{
      setSending(false);
      console.log("Album deleted");   
    });
   .catch (error => {
      setSending(false);
      console.log(error);
    });

  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    const unmount = db.collection("albums")
      .doc(album)
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        setImages(doc.data().images || []);
        setAlbumName(doc.data().name);
      });
      return unmount
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <header>
          <h1>{albumName}</h1>
          <p>Go to the <Link to="/">Home page</Link></p>
        </header>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <aside key={image.name}>
            <img src={image.url} alt="album" />
          </aside>
        ))}
      <input type="button" disabled={isSending} onClick={deleteDoc(index)} />
      </section>
      <footer>
        <NewPhoto currentAlbum={album} />
      </footer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes , indeed i did not, explain correctly.

I have a collection named = "albums", inside it, i have some document.

Inside of each document i have some images, with their name. Both are string value (image.name and image.url)

So, by adding a delete button in section i want to delete the corresponded images and update it in the firebase firestore.

Thaks for your help, i tried your code and have an error : 

"./src/Album.js
  Line 14:22:  'useCallback' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 52:40:  'isSending' is not defined    no-undef
"

Comment: @SouhailMohamed, I edited the answer above so that you don't face those errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works indeed fine now.

But like i expect, the funciton doesn't delete what i want.

The function delete 1 "album" document and not the "images" inside it.

To understand better, ther is a screenshot of my firestore : https://snipboard.io/ecnEfo.jpg

Comment: The structure of your data does not lend itself well to what you are trying to achieve, maybe a better solution would be to create a collection called images and have each one as a flat document, this way firestore can index faster and work more efficiently, with a property that links it back to the album.

Comment: I've not used `Firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(index)`  before but I've amended the answer to give you a hand. This blog helps out with some array stuff. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html please read the other firebase docs they are very helpful.