# How to call API and stores results in a state when a form submit is clicked using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I call an API then store its JSON results into a state when a form submit button is clicked using hooks?

In my code below, I'm using a `form`. When the user clicks the `submit` button an API is called based off parameters they gave, but when I try to store it in a state I get this error

```
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function Example() {

    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    const [storage, setStorage] = useState(null)

    const submitAction = async(data) => {
        let url = "..."
        url += data.param
        useEffect(async () => {
            setStorage(response.data...)
        }, [])
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit(submitAction)}>
                <select {...register('param')}>
                    <option value="something"> something </option>
                    ...
                </select>
                <button type={"submit"}submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}
```

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647287/how-to-send-request-on-click-react-hooks-way) and from what I understand, `useEffect(...)` has to come before `submitAction`. In `useEffect` I lock the API call based off a boolean variable `call API if boolean var = true`. But then I'm not sure how I'm supposed to pass my parameters I need for the API.

Comment: Your component must start with Uppercase `Example` not `example`, if you don't have that in your code

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `async` functions then use them in `useEffect` or `onEvent`.

Also use `async` and `await` together.

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from axios;

const Component = () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get/post(...);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
}
```

If you want to call `API` by click

**HTML**

```html
<form onSubmit={fetchData}>
    ...
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from axios;

const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get/post(...);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I'm very new to react and I'm having trouble translating your answer to the example I gave. Would you mind editing your answer so it's closer to my question?

Comment: Please read `react rules`, You can't define `useEffect` inside a function, `useEffect` is HOC. `useEffect` can't be async. You should define `async function` in your `Component` and use it inside `useEffect`, Need more explanation?